# What technologies should I use if I want to develop a real-time web-app?

Tags: web-apps, web-development, web, game, game-development

I'd like to develop a web application based on a chess game. It's something like [this](https://chess.com), but I have no idea about which technologies to use. I read several posts where the suggestion was to use socket.io and node.js (server-side). I want this project to be published on a real server, so I'm trying to find a technology supported over there, that join my requirements.

I worked in the past  with servlets and java (server-side) but it seems to be not the solution for this case.

I really appreciate if someone just explain me these concepts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is this tutorial I have found some time ago:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PfSwUOBL1YQ

It is very good and shows the basics of socket.io.

*For publishing*:

I would recommend hosting it on a Node.js Hosting website. There are alot out there you can find on google.

Making your own server is really hard and needs alot of time and money.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Do you think Visual Studio is it good to work with node.js?

Comment: Absolutely! I prefer using Visual Studio Code as it is lightweight.

Comment: I am not really sure about Visual Studio. I have never really used it. It is slow on my computer.